# PHP ltrim() not working as expected

Tags: php, function

I have this code..

```
$homepage1 = 'datastring=/mac_project/portfolio/kitchen/images/03.jpg';
$trimmed = ltrim($homepage1, 'datastring=/mac_project');
echo $trimmed;
```

I get the output as `folio/kitchen/images/03.jpg`. It's missing the `/port` from the `/portfolio` directory.

Full output should've been `/portfolio/kitchen/images/03.jpg`

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/function.ltrim.php) - *"You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the **character_mask** parameter"*

Comment: @Phil hmm Slashdot reader?

Comment: @ring0 Nope. That acronym pre-dates Slashdot by several decades at least

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do the simple `str_replace()` ?

```
$homepage1 = 'datastring=/mac_project/portfolio/kitchen/images/03.jpg';
$trimmed = str_replace('datastring=/mac_project','',$homepage1);
echo $trimmed;// "prints" /portfolio/kitchen/images/03.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter for `ltrim` is for **[character_mask](http://php.net/ltrim)**, which means all the chars in the list will be trimmed.

You could use `str_replace()`, or if you want to replace only at the beginning of the string by `preg_replace()`:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('~^datastring=/mac_project~', '', $homepage1);
```